# Calculating a series for$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{p-1}}{1+x^q} dx$ by interchanging sum with integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to show that $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{p-1}}{1+x^q} dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n}{p+nq}$$
whereas $p,q >0$. I thought, I might just use the geometric series and then interchange sum and integral, so I would have:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{p-1}}{1+x^q} dx = \int_0^1 x^{p-1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x^q)^n$$
That way, if interchanging the sum with the integral is valid I would arrive at my goal pretty easily. However, I am not quite sure if I am allowed to do this.

I know for a fact that the geometric series is uniformly convergent for every compact subset $K \subset [-1,1]$. The integrals of the partial sums seem to exist as well. But is compact convergence enough in this case? I know that I can interchange the sum and the integral if my partial sums converge uniformly on the whole interval (in this case $[0,1]$), but this does not seem to apply here. 
I also thought about using dominated convergence, but the upper boundary $g(x) :=\frac{1}{1-x^q}$  would not be an integrable function on this interval...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This won’t work for $ q >1$.

Comment: You have $x^q$ instead of $xq$ right?

Comment: @Shashi Yes, I am correcting it. thanks

Comment: And why is the mentioned $g(x) $ not integrable? It seems very integrable to me.

Comment: The dominated convergence theorem allows the interchange (use $x^{p-1}$ as the dominating function). That is, if you use the Lebesgue integral. If you use the Riemann integral, you need to do a bit more work since the DCT doesn't fully hold for the Riemann integral.

Comment: @Shashi I corrected the function as well. I do not think I can use $\frac{1}{1+x^q}$ as an upper bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the correct idea, the sequence $\int_0^{1-{1\over n}}{x^{p-1}\over{1+x^q}}dx$ is an increasinig and bounded sequence, this implies that

$\int_0^{1-{1\over n}} x^{p-1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x^q)^n$ is also increasing and bounded so it converges towards its sup

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints which may guide you in solving this problem. On another note, would love to know which textbook/website this problem came from - really interesting.

Here:

The solution involves the hypergeometric function.

[image: Solution]

More information on the hypergeometric function

[image: Another way to write the series]

Another way to write the function as a sum

[image: Taylor expansion at t=0]

Taylor expansion at $t=0$
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem was given to me, so if it was taken from a textbook, I could not tell you where it is from.